# Can AWS CloudFormation resources call !GetAtt on themselves?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to set up the Inventory configuration for an S3 bucket with CloudFormation. I want to get daily inventories of data in one subfolder, and have the inventories written to a different subfolder in the same bucket. I have defined the bucket as follows:

```yaml
S3Bucket:
  Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  Properties:
    # ...other properties...
    InventoryConfigurations:
    - Id: runs
      Enabled: true
      Destination:
        BucketAccountId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
        BucketArn: !GetAtt S3Bucket.Arn
        Format: CSV
        Prefix: inventory/runs/
      IncludedObjectVersions: Current
      OptionalFields: [ETag, Size, BucketKeyStatus]
      Prefix: runs/
      ScheduleFrequency: Daily
```

Unfortunately, the `!GetAtt S3Bucket.Arn` line seems to be failing, causing an error message like "Error: Failed to create changeset for the stack: , ex: Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state: For expression "Status" we matched expected path: "FAILED" Status: FAILED. Reason: Circular dependency between resource". If I use the actual ARN of the bucket in place of `!GetAtt S3Bucket.Arn` (it already exists from a previous version of the stack), then the deploy succeeds, so I know buckets can write Inventories to themselves.

So I guess my question is, is there a way to let Cfn resources call `!GetAtt` on themselves, so I don't have to hard-code the bucket ARN in `InventoryConfigurations`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is because AWS is not expecting you to publish the bucket inventory to the bucket itself. Shades of recursion.

Comment: @jarmod I've set the destination bucket for inventories to the same bucket previously - I'm not aware of such restriction; do you have any docs?

Comment: I'm not saying that it's a restriction or that it won't work. I'm saying that I suspect that AWS didn't expect anyone would want to do this, so they didn't make the inventory configuration a distinct CloudFormation resource type that you could then create independently of the S3 bucket (and hence use GetAtt).

Comment: @jarmod Ah OK, it's strange they haven't since it is supported

Comment: BTW, using static bucket names has its benefits, but if you do prefer to create an autogenerated, unique bucket name so you can launch multiple stacks from the same template then you should be able to do this by constructing the bucket name from a static prefix (e..g. `mybucket-`) and then a suffix based on the pseudo parameter `AWS::StackId`. You could use `!Split` on the stack ID to retrieve the final GUID part of it and append it to your bucket name. Something like: `!Select [2, !Split ["/", ${AWS::StackId}]]`. And use `!Join` to concatenate the suffix to the prefix.

Comment: @jarmod I agree it sounds weirdly recursive (kinda like having a bucket write bucket logs to itself), but taking inventory of one subfolder (prefix) and writing those inventories to another subfolder, as I'm doing here, seems like a valid/common use case. That's probably why AWS supports it.

Comment: And yeah, I considered the parameterized bucket name approach. What really sold me on auto-generated names was that they allow stack updates that have to replace the bucket. This might be moot tho, as replacing the bucket would require deleting the existing one, and Cfn can only do that if the bucket is empty...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can AWS CloudFormation resources call !GetAtt on themselves?

Unfortunately no, as the `!GetAtt` is used to reference *other* resources in the stack as you've experienced (other as in concrete resources that have already been created).

---

However, in your case, considering you know the bucket name, you could just [construct the bucket ARN yourself](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/s3-arn-format.html) directly.

Format:

> arn:aws:s3:::**bucket_name**

e.g. if the name is `test`, you can use `arn:aws:s3:::test`

```
Destination:
    BucketAccountId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
    BucketArn: 'arn:aws:s3:::test'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, in this case, I am not explicitly setting `BucketName` on the bucket, as that prevents updates that require replacement on the bucket resource. Therefore, I don't actually know the bucket's name at design time. Sounds like I'll just have to use a separate bucket for inventories...

Comment: How do you want to identify the bucket? You must have *some* way of identifying it?

Comment: CloudFormation will generate a random name for the bucket if you don't explicitly set the name yourself. Thus, you can't craft the ARN yourself in such a case.

Comment: While it might in practice turn out to be the same thing, I suspect the limitation is not that GetAtt can only reference *other* resources in the stack, but that it can only reference concrete, reified resources (i.e. that actually exist, whereas the S3 bucket in this scenario does not actually exist yet, and cannot be created because of the self-referential issue).